# Joint and Marginal Densities

Tags: probability

I am working a problem that is stated there are $12$ bears in a rescue center, $6$ brown bears and $6$ black bears. If $4$ are chosen at random for release, and $$X:=\text{the number of black bears released},$$ and $$Y:=\text{the number of brown bears released}$$ determine the joint density and the marginal density. I determined the joint density to be hypergeometric and using combinations $$\frac{(6,x)\cdot (6,y)}{12,4}.$$
From this I am having a very difficult time calculating the marginal densities, so either my joint density is incorrect or I really need help seeing how to calculate the marginal density.

Comment: do you understand what the meaning of the marginal distribution is?

Comment: Yes, I need to find the px(x) and py(y) of the px,y(x,y). Using either integration or summation. I am having issues doing those with the combinations.